# From php how the system() function is working?

Tags: php, linux, system

I am working in a project, where the script will run under Linux. It has many modules, which are written in C++. I need to call these modules from PHP.

My problem is as follows:

1. My module is one of the module in the software package.
2. Our software is having the PHP layers to take user input and store it in database, and also call the C++ engine when needed.
3. All modules are running and using some environment variable which was set by the base module.
4. There is one layer of PHP through we are getting the user inputs to our C++ engines.
5. I need to call an application (abc.out) from PHP and it will fill the database.

The problem is that I have to set one new environment variable before the application will work.

I am getting the old environment variable using `getenv()` then appending a path to it and setting again. I have used `putenv()` to set the new environment variable.

After setting the environment variable I am using the `system()` to call that application from PHP and it is working.

My doubt is whether this environment variable change will affect other modules those are running.

One thing is that if we use `system()` for multiple operations, I can set the environment variable and call my application both from the same `system()` call. Here my doubt is whether this will also affect the other application which are running, or only the particular application which being called with `system()`.

That is `system()` is a creating a new session for each program what we call by it or not?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, php is open source :-)  You need to look in the file [ext/standard/exec.c](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/exec.c).  system is implemented as a call to php_exec_ex, which via php_exec uses a macro called [VCWD_POPEN](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/TSRM/tsrm_virtual_cwd.h), which on a Linux system uses a [popen()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/popen) system call.

So, each call to [PHP system()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php) on a Linux system will be executed through a fresh [popen()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/popen) system call, so yes, the separate calls are isolated.  I didn't check for Windows.

Comment: Thanks fvu ,
As you said each system() will create a different/fresh environment so ,If i call a putenv() then call my application by system() ,then it will run on that new environment/session and it will not affect to other application running.If it is correct then I can use this in my module.Thanks again..

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer may I ask you to accept it?  Thank you!

Comment: I got one doubt ,I came across shell_exec() it also doing the same,so my requirement is I have to run that application with out affecting to other application,How can I do this. with system() or shell_exec()

Comment: Internally you will see that shell_exec also uses VCWD_POPEN so it's identical.  So the same concept of isolation that is true for system applies to shell_exec - check out the source, you will see these functions are very much related to each other.  I also put a link to the git source of exec.c in my post, that should answer most questions you might still have.